# Question is about fixed point theorem in $(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis

which of the following statement is true?

1. Any continuous function from the open unit interval $(0, 1)$ to itself has a fixed
   point.
2. any continious function from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1)$ has a fixed point

I think both option 1) and option 2) are true  if we take identity function that is $f(x) = x$ then by intermediate theorem it has a fixed point..so both statement are true..

Is my answer is correct or not ..pliz verified it and tell me the soluition

Comment: What *exactly* is the difference between question 1 and 2? They look exactly the same to me...perhaps you meant in one of them the **closed** unit interval $\;[0,1]\;$  ?

Comment: @DonAntonio,,,,my english is weak...im not getting exact meaning of "Any continuous function from the open unit interval (0, 1) to itself has a fixed point.".....can u elaborate this meaning in simple manner

Comment: You still haven't explained what's the difference between those two question 1,2, because they look **exactly the same** ...look!

Comment: ok,,now i realized both are same@DonAntonio,,thanks u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two questions are about *any* function such that ..., so you can't just look at a specific case like $f(x)=x.$

For the *open* interval $(0,1),$ use that it is homeomorphic to the entire real line, which has a fixed-point free continuous self-map $g(x)=x+1.$

Comment: @ cofeemath that mean both option are correct,,,,,,but answer given that option 2 is false that is any continious function from (0,1) to (0,1) has a fixed point....can u give me counter example why it is false ?

Comment: @lomberlego In the two questions it's important whether you mean $(0,1),$ which does *not* include the endpoints $0,1,$ or $[0,1]$ which does include the endpoints.

Comment: i mean (0,1),,that doesnot include the end points

Comment: @ coffeemath,,,,im not getting the fixed point free continious  meaning ?

Comment: ok,,i got it,,thank u so much @ coffeemath

Comment: To avoid reference to the homeomorphism, at the expense of using the open interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ use the map $f(x)=\arctan(\tan x+1).$

Comment: thanks a lots @ coffeemath